# Value undefined after being resolved from Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, node.js-fs

I think the problem here might be wrong awaits, or the fact that I have a wrapped up callback inside the promise and I'm trying to resolve the promise inside that callback. Not sure how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated!

```
async function pointInRegion(latitude, longitude) {
  await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const coordinate = [longitude, latitude]
      const pt = turf.point(coordinate); // tried adding await here
      fs.readFile("./regions.geojson", async function (err, data) { // tried adding await here
        if (err) throw err;
        const geojson = JSON.parse(data);
        for (const feature of geojson.features) {
          const inRegion = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, feature) // tried adding await here
          if (inRegion) {
            console.log (feature.properties.name)
            return resolve(feature.properties.name)
          }
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

I call it in the main function like:

```
const calculatedRegion = await pointInRegion(latitude, longitude)
console.log(calculatedRegion) // prints undefined
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your `pointInRegion` function

Comment: What about the 'return resolve(feature.properties.name)'

Comment: That is _inside_ of the Promise you create, but you aren't actually returning that Promise. (e.g. try `return new Promise(....`)

Comment: @nickcoding2 it's in another function. Namely `async function (err, data) {` Even then, `resolve` doesn't have a return value.

Comment: [`require('node:fs/promises')`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api)

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You aren't returning your `Promise` to any callers
2. You don't need `async` or `await` here, the consuming function(s) will call `await` on the return value of `pointInRegion`

Modifications with comments:

```
function pointInRegion(latitude, longitude) {
  // no need to await here, calling functions will await
  // return await is also not needed
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const coordinate = [longitude, latitude]
      const pt = turf.point(coordinate);
      fs.readFile("./regions.geojson", function (err, data) { 
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        const geojson = JSON.parse(data);
        for (const feature of geojson.features) {
          const inRegion = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, feature);
          if (inRegion) {
            console.log (feature.properties.name);
            // no return needed for resolve
            resolve(feature.properties.name);
          }
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      // no return needed for reject
      reject(err);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: There's also no need for `async`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I guess it makes sense that the problem was me not actually returning the Promise. Thanks!